# .gitignore not ignoring the sub-directory .DS_Store files

Tags: git, github

I tried everypossible solution I found here but none working. This is my .gitignore file:

```
*.pyc
.DS_Store
static/.DS_Store
```

It ignores .DS_Store files in the root directory of my repo but doesn't in the subdirectories like the directory named static. I even tried to add the follwoing in the .gitidnore files but they also don't work:

```
*/.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
*DS_Store
```

Comment: Were the files in `static/.DS_Store` already part of the repository _before_ you added this rule to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Yes, all the files in the static directory were the part of the repo. I had also made some commits in my repo before even adding a **.gitignore** file.

Comment: *.DS_Store should resolve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the files in `static/.DS_Store` *before* the rules you have to `.gitignore` can take effect.  Run this from the Git bash:

```
git rm -r --cached static/.DS_Store
```

This will delete these files from the repo, while retaining them on your local file system, which is what you want.  After running this command, you should be able to see the delete changes by running `git status`.

Comment: `Not working` ... this is a very helpful comment.  What does `git status` tell you after running `git rm`?

Comment: Yeah! it deleted the static/.DS_Sore file. Thanks a lot. :)